# Issue with gem 'minitest-hyper'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing

Am using minitest-hyper gem to produce result of testcases in html. but when I run my test cases am getting below issue

1) When i run TEST_OPTS="--html" rake test:units

2) I am getting invalid option: --html Test::Unit automatic runner.

3) I am using gem 'gem "minitest-hyper", :require => false'
gem 'rails', git: 'https://github.com/rails/rails.git', branch: '3-2-stable'
ruby 2.1.2

4) I tried for sample its working, but in project it's not working.

Comment: If you go over to https://github.com/chriskottom/minitest-hyper/issues and submit an issue, I'll try to take a look at it as soon as I can.

Comment: I took a quick look at this.  Rails wasn't using Minitest as the default testing framework until 4.0, so extensions won't work until at least that release.  (Possibly not until later releases since 4.0.x depends on Minitest 4.2 which might not be compatible with extensions developed against MT 5.x.)